# ez publish can't access admin interface

Tags: content-management-system, ezpublish

I'm trying to install the ez Publish CMS for a futur project. I'm going through the installation without much issues, I can access the welcome page of the CMS on this url: 127.0.0.1:8080 using a virtual machine with debian/apache/php5.6/mysql (rewrite enabled), but I can't access the admin interface, I tried '127.0.0.1:8080/ez' as it's explained in documentation but I get a 404 error.

I have no error logs on the server and the application seems to be working. I'm a beginner with this CMS so I really don't see why it doesn't work.

I followed this installation tutorial: [ez publish composer tutorial](https://doc.ez.no/display/DEVELOPER/Installation+Using+Composer) , as you will see I'm using composer in my installation. I had no error during the installation steps, does anyone had this problem before?

It will be great if someone can share a solution, I won't be able to do much with the CMS if I can't even log in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution**

Never mind, looking everywhere I finally figure it out, There was a vhost file in the doc folder for apache, using this I was able to access the admin url.